# building AOSP 13 error:"bionic-benchmarks-glibc" depends on undefined module "libtinyxml2"

Tags: android, linux, node-modules, android-source

AILED: out/soong/build.ninja
cd "$(dirname "out/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_build")" && BUILDER="$PWD/$(basename "out/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_build")" && cd / && env -i  "$BUILDER"     --top "$TOP"     --soong_ou
t "out/soong"     --out "out"     -o out/soong/build.ninja --globListDir build --globFile out/soong/globs-build.ninja -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list --available_env out/soo
ng/soong.environment.available --used_env out/soong/soong.environment.used.build Android.bp
error: bionic/tests/Android.bp:340:1: "libBionicStandardTests" depends on undefined module "libtinyxml2"
error: bionic/benchmarks/Android.bp:123:1: "bionic-benchmarks-glibc" depends on undefined module "libtinyxml2"
10:35:47 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the repo tinyxml2.
Get it from here
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/tinyxml2/